# PHP An iterator cannot be used with foreach by reference

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an object that implements `Iterator` and holds 2 arrays: "entries" and "pages". Whenever I loop through this object, I want to modify the entries array but I get the error `An iterator cannot be used with foreach by reference` which I see started in [PHP 5.2](http://php.net/manual/en/migration52.error-messages.php).

My question is, how can I use the `Iterator` class to change the value of the looped object while using `foreach` on it?

My code:

```
//$flavors = instance of this class:
class PaginatedResultSet implements \Iterator {
    private $position = 0;
    
    public $entries = array();
    public $pages = array();

    //...Iterator methods...
}

//looping
//throws error here
foreach ($flavors as &$flavor) {
    $flavor = $flavor->stdClassForApi();
}
```

The reason for this is that sometimes `$flavors` will *not* be an instance of my class and instead will just be a simple array. I want to be able to modify this array easily regardless of the type it is.

Comment: why not just check if it's a class or an array first and then treat it appropriately?

Comment: @MuppetGrinder Because I use these methods in many places and I don't want to have to do that check every time, instead just in 1 place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just tried creating an iterator which used:

```
public function &current() {
    $element = &$this->array[$this->position];
    return $element;
}
```

But that still did not work.

The best I can recommend is that you implement `\ArrayAccess`, which will allow you to do this:

```
foreach ($flavors as $key => $flavor) {
    $flavors[$key] = $flavor->stdClassForApi();
}
```

**Using generators:**

Updating based on Marks comment on generators, the following will allow you to iterate over the results without needing to implement `\Iterator` or `\ArrayAccess`.

```
class PaginatedResultSet {
    public $entries = array();

    public function &iterate()
    {
        foreach ($this->entries as &$v) {
            yield $v;
        }
    }
}

$flavors = new PaginatedResultSet(/* args */);

foreach ($flavors->iterate() as &$flavor) {
    $flavor = $flavor->stdClassForApi();
}
```

This is a feature available in PHP 5.5.

Comment: It's also possible to access elements of a Generator "by reference", so that might be an alternative approach

Comment: I ended up going with implementing both \ArrayAccess and \Iterator and then using the $key => $val style instead of by reference. This worked perfectly.

Comment: @MarkBaker I still need to look into how those work, I'm a little puzzled on what they mean when they say the state of the function doesn't change on each call.

Comment: @Flosculus - it means that the variables inside the Generator don't go out of scope while you're iterating over the generator, only when it terminates (is no longer valid).... I'm currently writing a book on Generators in PHP

Comment: @MarkBaker Made an update for generators.  Thanks, was educational.

Comment: Just `ArrayAccess` is enough to allow you to use a `foreach` loop on the class _and_ use references, no need to do `$key => $flavor` + `$flavors[$key] = …`, `&$flavor` + `$flavor = …` works just fine, at least in PHP 7.1 where I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon Flosculus' solution, if you don't want to reference the key each time you use the iterated variable, you can assign a reference to it to a new variable in the first line of your foreach.

```
foreach ($flavors as $key => $f) {
  $flavor = &$flavors[$key];
  $flavor = $flavor->stdClassForApi();
}
```

This is functionally identical to using the key on the base object, but helps keep code tidy, and variable names short...  If you're into that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you implemented the iterator functions in your calss, I would suggest to add another method to the class "setCurrent()":

```
//$flavors = instance of this class:
class PaginatedResultSet implements \Iterator {
    private $position = 0;

    public $entries = array();
    public $pages = array();

    /* --- Iterator methods block --- */
    private $current;

    public function setCurrent($value){
        $this->current = $value;
    }

    public function current(){
        return $this->current;
    }
    //...Other Iterator methods...
}
```

Then you can just use this function inside the foreach loop:

```
foreach ($flavors as $flavor) {
    $newFlavor = makeNewFlavorFromOldOne($flavor)
    $flavors -> setCurrent($newFlavor);
}
```

If you need this function in other classes, you can also define a new iterator and extend the Iterator interface to contain setCurrent()