# foreach subiteration considers only last element

Tags: php, opencart

I have a following code:

```
foreach ($params as $param)
{
    foreach ($exclude_by_attribute as $exc)
    {
        if ($param['name']==$exc)
        {
            unset($param['name']);
            unset ($param);
        }
    }
}
```

But it unsets only last element. Element in `if` statement is taking from another array. How can I remove all the elements? Also I will put some sample xml data:

```
<offer id="lyustra_sl113_303_03" type="vendor.model" available="true">
<picture>http://vokruglamp.ru/export/img/422/27059a11c58ade9b03bde05c2ca7c285.jpeg</picture>
<name>someName</name>
<vendor>ST Luce</vendor>
<url>http://somesite.com/catalog/product/lyustra_sl113_303_03/</url>
<currencyId>RUB</currencyId>
<categoryId>188</categoryId>
<image>http://somesite.com/export/img/422/27059a11c58ade9b03bde05c2ca7c285.jpeg</image>
<param name="code">1111</param>
<param name="brand">ST Luce</param>
<param name="someparam">value</param>
<param name="another">value</param>
```

Some of those paras I want to remove. Based on the exclude_by_attribute array.

Comment: Not sure if the `unset ($param);` should be in there.

Comment: Nigel that is the proper answer

Comment: Yes. Sorry. The params array is comming from simpleXml object. And to me it sims like $param keeps the value of $param['name'].

Comment: If you want to remove the element based on having a certain attribute, you could try `unset ($param[0]);`

Comment: Thank you. But that way I get a warning that node is no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

so modifying your code :

```
   foreach ($params as $key => $param)
    {
        foreach ($exclude_by_attribute as $exc)
        {
            if ($param['name']==$exc)
            {
                unset ($params[$key]);
                break; 

            }
        }
    }
```

For better coding you should use array_filter

```
$result = array_filter($params, function($val) use ($exclude_by_attribute) {
    return !in_array($val,$exclude_by_attribute );
   });
```

Comment: Sorry, But with no luck. foreach loop just hangs. Function doesn't do the job. Only last element is beeing removed.

Answer (score 0):

`$param` is a copy of the sub-array, so unsetting elements of it doesn't modify the original `$params` array.

Use a reference variable to make it update the original sub-array:

```
foreach ($params as &$param)
```

Also, take `unset($param);` out of the loop, as this will break the reference link. You should do it after the loop is done.

Since `$params` is a generator, you first have to turn it into an array.

```
$params_array = [];
foreach ($params as $param) {
    $params_array[] = $param;
}
```

Then use `$params_array` in the rest of the script, including the above loop that unsets elements.

You can also replace the inner loop with the `in_array()` function.

```
<?php

$params_array = [
    ['name' => 'code', 'value' => 1],
    ['name' => 'brand', 'value' => 2],
    ['name' => 'someparam', 'value' => 3],
    ['name' => 'another', 'value' => 4]
];

$exclude_by_attribute = ['brand', 'someparam'];

foreach ($params_array as &$param) {
    if (in_array($param['name'], $exclude_by_attribute)) {
        unset($param['name']);
    }
}

unset($param);
print_r($params_array);
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/DaRwYy)

Comment: Sorry, but now I am getting fatal error: An iterator cannot be used with foreach by reference

Comment: I assumed `$params` was an array. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798586/php-an-iterator-cannot-be-used-with-foreach-by-reference

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't help much. That brought me to the setuation like in very beginning.

Comment: Create an array of the generator values, then iterate over that.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to modify a generator in place.

Comment: Would be greate, but then I am loossing attribute names. That I have to remove.

Comment: Got the same result as in a question with an array to.

Comment: Can you add sample data to the question?

Comment: Got it. Sample data is in question.

Comment: I don't see how that's related to `$params`. It looks like part of XML.

Comment: Yes that is a part. Other parts are fine. It is just to big to post it here.

Comment: Are you trying to delete elements from the XML using this loop? It just updates the array, not the original XML.

Comment: You should be using methods of the `DOMDocument` class to change the XML.

Comment: Not really. I want just to update an array and then put a new values from xml to DB.

Comment: But are you trying to remove the `name` element, or remove `$param` from the `$params` array?

Comment: `array_filter()` may be what you really want.

Comment: Basicly name and it's value.

Comment: BTW, the inner loop can be replaced with simply `if (in_array($param['name'], $exlude_by_attribute))`